# Bootstrap menu sliding effect

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to add sliding effect(slideUp and slideDown) for bootstrap menu.
I have written below JavaScript code.

Basic HTML Code:

```js
jQuery('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(800);
});
jQuery('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(800, function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="menu menu--main nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="expanded dropdown open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="expanded dropdown-submenu">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="/node/1" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="/node/2" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/2">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="/node/3" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Above code is getting apply only to 1st level of element, but not getting applied to 2nd level of element.
2nd level of element is having "dropdown-submenu" class. I have change the class name but then also its not working as expected.
please help me solve this issue.

Comment: You have bind events for bootstrap show and hide on `.dropdown` elements but haven't assigned this class to the 2nd level dropdown

Comment: Even if I add .dropdown class to 2nd level dropdown, then also its not working.
and even if I add one more same JS code and put .dropdown-submenu class in place of .dropdown class, then also its not working

Comment: Have you checked this? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

I think u shud follow the official documentation of bootstrap 4 navigation menu, Anyways i edited your code, i dont know why were u using first() method, there is not need for that.

**Official bootsrap nav menu:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

try following code. let me know your response

```
jQuery('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown(800);
});

jQuery('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
  // e.preventDefault();
  var self = $(this);
  jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp(800, function(){
    self.removeClass('open');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have added your suggested code in my js file
but its not working as excepted. .dropdown-submenu class items are now opening right left instead up and down.